# I want to RUN a script file for the DOCKERIZED ODOO server to run all my custom modules with all the base modules

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-10, docker-image

I have installed **DOCKER** in my Ubuntu and also the **ODOO** image as a container in the Docker, the odoo image is running successfully over the docker but i fail to run my test script over it.

And i have my own script file referring to run my custom modules and other files which has the following content:

> tests.sh

```
ADDONS_DIR="./addons"
DELETE_DB="dropdb testdb"


MODULE_LIST="hr_contract_leaves,hr_employee_birthdat_reminder,hr_employee_documents,hr_employee_emergency_contract,hr_employee_loan,hr_employee_medical_information,hr_employee_statutory_detail,hr_payslip_reports,hr_recruitment_interviewer,hr_recruitment_job_stage_survey,hr_recruitment_reports,account,account_accountant,board,calendar,contacts,crm,fleet,hr,hr_attendance,hr_expense,hr_holidays,hr_payroll,hr_recruitment,hr_timesheet,im_livechat,lunch,mail,maintenance,mass_mailing,mrp,mrp_repair,note,point_of_sale,project,project_issue,purchase,sale,survey,website,website_blog,website_event,website_forum,website_slides"
echo "Testing for modules: $MODULE_LIST"


RUN_ODOO="/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/odoo-bin --addons-path=/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-server/addons --log-level error -d testdb --init $MODULE_LIST --test-enable --stop-after-init 2>&1 | tee test_results.log"
echo "Starting tests with the following command: $RUN_ODOO"
eval $RUN_ODOO
echo "Tests Finished"

RESULT=$(grep "FAIL\|ERROR" test_results.log)

echo "Failure in tests: $RESULT"

echo "Cleaning up"

echo "Deleting Databse"
eval $DELETE_DB
echo "Database Deleted"

echo "Removing log file"
rm test_results.log
echo "Log file deleted"

echo "Clean up finished"


if [ ! -z "$RESULT" ] 
  then
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
  else
    echo "PASSED"
    exit 0
fi
```

Please, anyone could help me in running my script file over the docker odoo, as **I'm new with this so i would hope a step by step guide**.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What is the issue? Failed to run something doesn't explain what went wrong

Comment: I want to run this test script in my docker odoo, and i want it to be execute it.

Comment: That still does not explain what problem you are having exactly. Please be more specific, as the question is likely to be closed as unclear otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the default [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/f8af1a80b14d9e594fdef4df2ff78e655352473c/10.0/entrypoint.sh) of the image, you can specify the `--entrypoint` option to `docker run` like this:

```
docker run -d --entrypoint=test.sh odoo:10.0
```

This will cause the container to run your `test.sh` when it starts, instead of the default `entrypoint.sh`. This isn't recommended, as you can see from the `entrypoint.sh` that it supports other database-related configurations.

If all your `test.sh` script does is to add your own modules and provide some additional options, you can:

1. Override the default [odoo.conf](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/f8af1a80b14d9e594fdef4df2ff78e655352473c/10.0/odoo.conf) file to provide your own `addons_path`,
2. Mount the your custom addon folder with
3. Specify the options as command arguments to `docker run`

with this:

```
docker run -p 8069:8069 \
  -v /path/to/your_config_file:/etc/odoo  \
  -v /path/to/your_addons_folder:/mnt/extra-addons \
  --name odoo \
  --link testdb:testdb \
  -t odoo:10.0 --log-level error -d testdb --init $MODULE_LIST --test-enable --stop-after-init
```

You shouldn't have to worry about specifying your own log file like `test_results.log`, as you can see the container logs using `docker logs`.